# How to create Quantiles in R, dependend on household income and household expeditures

Tags: r, dplyr

my goal at the moment is to create a graphic of quintiles over the years. Similar to the picture. For example I want to see how the share of housing expenditure of the household income rises over the years for the lowest income quintile.

I create the quintiles for the household income with `zz<-do.call("rbind", tapply(f$hinc, f$year, quantile,seq(0,1,1/5)))`. My Problem is, that I do not know you to match this information with my dataframe and that I don't know how I match the quintiles of the household income with its housing expenditures. I would like to see the shares that the different income quintiles have to spend on housing expenditure, but I have no Idea how to get there.

Sorry for the vague question. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi Philipp, please provide a reproducible example with some data so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi Philipp, it has been a while since I used R but have you looked at the cut function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut?  I used to use it together with the Cartography library's getBreaks function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cartography/versions/2.3.0/topics/getBreaks. I divided my data into quantile classes and labeled them using the cut function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. For each observation this code adds the index of the income quantile by year to  the dataframe `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(
  year = sample(c(2013, 2018), 20, replace = TRUE),
  inc = rnorm(20, 20000, 5000),
)

quant <- function(inc) {
  breaks <- quantile(inc, probs = seq(0, 1, .2), na.rm = TRUE)
  index <- findInterval(inc, breaks, rightmost.closed = TRUE, all.inside = TRUE)
}
# Add quantile
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(year) %>%
   mutate(quant = quant(inc))

# Plot of mean income
df %>%
  group_by(year, quant) %>% 
  summarise(mean_inc = mean(inc)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, mean_inc, color = factor(quant), group = quant)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: My pleasure. By the way. If you want to use household weighting factors have a look at `Hmisc::wtd.quantile`.